# I have 2 fields 1 is CKEDITOR and other one is signature text field when I am trying to update in signature text field ckeditor field is not updating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor

I am getting issue in Ckeditor I have ckeditor textarea and signature text field when I am trying to update in signature it has to update in ckeditor signature area.

Here is my code

```
// Function to update subject and body based on start date
   function updateSubjectAndBody(startDate) {
     const form = $('#formCpiStop');
     const fromField = form.find('#from');
     const toField = form.find('#to');
     const subjectParagraph = form.find('#subjectParagraph');
    // Format the selected date as "Full day Month and date, year"
    const formattedDate = startDate ? new Date(startDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }) : '';
   // Get the values from the fields
    const from = fromField.val() || '';
    const to = toField.val() || '';
    const signature = $('#cpistopsignature').val() || '';
    const subjectText = `Request for deployment for ${formattedDate}  - Please Acknowledge`;
   // Set the updated content to the subject paragraph
   subjectParagraph.html(subjectText);
   // Body content for CKEditor (excluding From and To)
   const bodyContent = `
   <p>Dear Team,</p>
   <p>This is a request for successfully publish thethe tonight's ${formattedDate} for . 
    We will inform you once the release is complete.</p>
    <p>${signature}</p> <!-- Append signature to body content -->
    `;
   console.log(bodyContent);
  // Update CKEditor content directly
 if (CKEDITOR.instances.bodyTextarea) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.bodyTextarea.setData(bodyContent);
 }
 }
```

Here is the HTML field

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subjectCpiStop"><i class="fas fa-heading"></i> Subject</label>
      <p id="subjectParagraph"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cpistopsignature"><i class="fas fa-signature"></i> Signature</label>
      <input type="text" id="cpistopsignature" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong why the ckeditor not updating the signature field

Note I am not getting any error but ckeditor field is not updating

Working URL [URL](https://onecompiler.com/html/3zx8vbyt6)